# GitHub Action Cron Job - First Thursday of Every month

Tags: cron, github-actions

I know how to run a cron job on the first thursday of every month, as per this post: [How to schedule a cron for the first Thursday of every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58413332/how-to-schedule-a-cron-for-the-first-thursday-of-every-month)

I'm wanting to do this within a GitHub Action though, and I don't believe it supports the additional commands?

My yaml is as follows, but obviously the cron is completely wrong.  Any suggestions?

```yaml
name: daily-cron-job
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 2 * * *'
jobs:
  cron:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: populate-previous-month
        run: |
          curl --request POST \
          --url 'https://example.com' \
          --header 'Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.ACTION_KEY }}'
```

Comment: Seems like you could set this up to run every Thursday, then exit if the day-of-month is above seven. That's what the cronjob solutions are doing.

Comment: Don't suppose you know how to do that in actions? I'm not too familiar with them

Answer (score 1):

Here's the idea of Nick ODell. I haven't tested that it really runs though.

```yaml
name: daily-cron-job
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 2 * * THU'

jobs:
  cron:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: populate-previous-month
        run: |
          if [ `date +'%d' | sed 's/^0*//'` -le 7 ]; then
            echo "hello first thursday of the month"
          else
            echo "didn't match"
          fi
```