# How can I trigger GitHub Actions on every 3rd Saturday of a month?

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, github-actions, ui-automation

I want to trigger my UI tests on every 3rd Saturday of every month so that the application is tested after code is moved.

This is my current trigger:

```yaml
on: 
  schedule:
    - cron:  '00 00 * * 6'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about the [`schedule` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule) in the [POSIX cron syntax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html#tag_20_25_07) which can only express every weekday:

```yaml
on: schedule: - cron: '22 2 * * 6' # At 02:22, only on Saturday
```

As it runs every Saturday, it will run on every third Saturday as well.

If you can live with that, you can consider your question answered.

However, as a Posix cron expression does not support to specify the n-th Weekday in a month, it is common then to not execute the job if it is not the correct day. Within the crontab this could be with the command itself<sup>1</sup>, an option that is also available with a `cron` expression for a Microsoft Github Action Trigger, same same but different:

With [`jobs.<job_id>.if`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif) [**Expressions**](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions) it is possible to formulate whether or not your job is being run.

As no date expressions exist for it but it can operate on the output of a previous job<sup>2</sup>, a previous job can take care of the shell expression for the third Saturday (if, and only if, it runs on a Saturday):

```yaml
  - name: Get number of Saturday on a Saturday
    id: number-of-saturday-on-a-saturday
    run: >-
      printf >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
      "VALUE=%s"
      "$((($(date +%-d)-1)/7+1))" # (3)
  - name: Test Foo
    run: foo test
    if: steps.number-of-saturday-on-a-saturday.outputs.VALUE == 3
```

---

1. [Answer to **How to schedule a cron for the first Thursday of every month?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58414763/367456)
2. [Answer to **Get current date and time in GitHub workflows**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60942437/367456), the procedure has changed, currently see [**Example of setting an output parameter**](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#example-of-setting-an-output-parameter)
3. C.f. [date(1) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) and [2.5.4 Arithmetic Expansion - POSIX Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04)

Comment: `"$((($(date +%d)-1)/7+1))" # (3)` fails with `bash: (09: value too great for base (error token is "09")`. Replace with `"$((($(date +%-d)-1)/7+1))" # (3)` (added hyphen - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65848366)

Comment: @froque: Thanks for the pointer, fixed by adding the hyphen-minus to not have the d format the zero padding.