# How can I propagate my commit message to downstream GitHub Actions runs?

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I have two GitHub Actions workflows: `infra` and `build`. A successful `infra` run will trigger a `build` run by way of the following configuration:

```yaml
name: infra

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
```

```yaml
name: build

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [ infra ]
    types: [ completed ]
    branches: [ main ]
```

Each `infra` workflow run is named after the commit message that triggered it. However, each `build` run is just named "build".

Is it possible to propagate the name of one workflow run to downstream runs that are triggered in this way? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe [`run-name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#run-name) is useful here?

Answer (score 0):

*`infra`* has the commit data in the [github context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) [push event object](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push). its commit message information can be passed as [output](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) to other jobs.

in general it works by setting the id and then the output.

the other job, e.g. *`build`* then can refer to it, for example as suggested by *[Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75978562/how-can-i-propagate-my-commit-message-to-downstream-github-actions-runs#comment134005277_75978562)* via [`run-name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#run-name).

```
run-name: Deploy to ${{ inputs.deploy_target }} by @${{ github.actor }}
```

*(Example of run-name)*

A recent example setting and obtaining output is in the [answer to *How can I trigger github actions on every 3rd Saturday of a month?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75975946/367456). As this question requires [output from jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs), it need to be extended with the job output bindings:

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Map a step output to a job output
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.test }}
      output2: ${{ steps.step2.outputs.test }}
    steps:
      - id: step1
        run: echo "test=hello" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
      - id: step2
        run: echo "test=world" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - env:
          OUTPUT1: ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}}
          OUTPUT2: ${{needs.job1.outputs.output2}}
        run: echo "$OUTPUT1 $OUTPUT2"
```

*(Example: Defining outputs for a job)*